# Что делает эта строчка?

Tags: c++, ооп

Это код конструктора глубокого копирования. Work имя класса.

```
Work(const Work& copy) {
// body
}
```

Comment: Это не код, а заготовка, которая не делает ничего.

Comment: Что там в параметрах написано? Ссылка какая-то, что она делает?

Comment: Это наверняка копирующий конструктор класса  Work

Comment: Как что? Вы же сами написали - конструктор копирования. Вот и передается в конструктор ссылка на копируемый объект. А вот глубокое копирование или поверхностное или вообще никакого - неизвестно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Work(const Work& copy) {
// body
}

const Work& copy
```

На вход конструктора подается ссылка на экземпляр copy типа Work